# MySQL - Trying to find all points inside a Polygon

Tags: mysql, spatial

I am trying to query all from a table of points, all of the points that are inside a certain polygon. I have tried to use st_contains() and for some reason it just won't work.
To made it simple, I have made a table with the points (1,1),(0,0),(100,100) I have used:

```
GeomFromText('Point(0 0)')
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT id, astext(point) FROM points WHERE st_within(point,GeomFromText('Polygon(10 10, 10 -10, -10 -10, -10 10, 10 10)'))
```

I have also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094603/which-function-is-good-to-check-whether-the-given-lat-lng-is-inside-the-polygo/22101548#22101548), which made me feel confident that there is something very big that I'm missing...

Please, tell me what I'm doing wrong...
Thanks :)

Comment: Already asked and answered on [gis](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77269/does-mysql-has-function-which-will-return-the-points-inside-polygon).

Comment: Hi @hd1, thank you for your answer.I have seen this questions, but there is still something wrong with my code and I can't figure out what...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is very important that the "Polygon Creation String" will use at least 2 sets of parentheses, even if it's a 1-line polygon. for example:
GOOD Polygon Creation:

```
GeomFromText('Polygon((10 10,10 -10,-10 -10,10 10))')
```

BAD Polygon Creation:

```
GeomFromText('Polygon(10 10,10 -10,-10 -10,10 10)')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to determine if a point is within a polygon (winding number or the even odd rule).

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHs2Ugxo7-8
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule

This depends how you wish to treat a polygon.